# Possible to bind an event listener to a (hypothetical) onChangeInnerHTML event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, events, jquery-events

In my app, I have an OL tag whose contents are changed by various other dynamic events. Is there some way to put a listener on that OL so that I can execute a function whenever its contents are altered in any way? In this example I need to update a count of items in the list which appears in another spot in the interface.

I am using jQuery if that helps.

The contents of the OL are being changed with `OL.append()` and `LI.remove()`, in case those methods have some special events that I don't know about

Comment: If *you* are changing the contents of the `<ol>` then surely you don't need an event to tell you that you've just done so... right?

Comment: you're right. But there are many parts of the code that change the contents of this OL. I was hoping to stay as DRY as possible by harnessing an existing DOM event, instead of adding an additional function call to everything that changes the contents of the OL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reference to J-P's statement, if you want it event driven you could use custom events..

```
$('#myDiv').bind('contentChange', function() {
   // do stuff
});
```

When you change the innerHTML of #myDiv:

```
$('#myDiv').html('new Html').trigger('contentChange');
```

but, er, not sure why ya'd want to..

Comment: thanks everyone, it is sort of a silly question. i always forget about custom events ;). i ended up just making an additional function call in each place i update the list.

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin called livequery that will run code when elements are added to the DOM.

I assume `li` items are being added. With livequery, you can do something like this:

```
$('#myol li').livequery(function() {...});
```

It can also run code when items are removed:

```
$('#myol li').livequery(
     function() {...},  // Run when added
     function() {...}   // Run when removed
);
```

http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs

---

**EDIT:**

This assumes you don't have access to the code that is altering the DOM. If you do, **Dan Herberden** has a good solution.